# Numpy combine two different linspaces into a coordinate matrix

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

```
mat=[]

for x in np.linspace(x_min, x_max,num_x):
    y=np.linspace(y_min, y_max,num_y)
    mat.append(list(zip([x]*len(y),y)))
mat=np.array(mat)
```

I could do the above using loops but I am looking for a more efficient method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `np.meshgrid`, note that it retuns one N-D array for each coordinate, you must operate on those to get a matrix of coordinate pairs

> Return coordinate matrices from coordinate vectors.
>
> Make N-D coordinate arrays for vectorized evaluations of N-D scalar/vector fields over N-D grids, given one-dimensional coordinate arrays x1, x2,…, xn.

```py
x = np.linspace(x_min, x_max,num_x)
y = np.linspace(y_min, y_max,num_y)

XY = np.meshgrid(x,y)
# Here you have a tuple of 2 coordinate matrix

mat = np.array(XY).transpose()
# Transpose will transform your (2,num_y,num_x) array into
# the desired (num_x,num_y,2) array.
```